# jQuery and jQueryMobile or either one?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

It will be great if some can suggest weather or not to use jQuery for mobile web application for low bandwidth, also need to know if both jQuery and jQueryMobile will be needed or I can just use jQueryMobile for mobile web applications.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery Mobile is not a standalone library. It requires jQuery http://jquerymobile.com/download/

Use these minified cdn links would be good

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
```

And jQuery Mobile team constantly work on performance with almost each release

[image]

And if you are more concerned on speed. Then jQuery Mobile has decoupled it's library in modules so you can only use what interaction you want.

And soon jQuery Mobile is going to release a download builder for this

> **Download builder: In the works**
>
> Now that we’ve decoupled most of the UI widgets, we’ve set the stage
>   for there to be a download builder. This will let you build a custom
>   version of jQuery Mobile to only include the parts you need. For
>   example, you could just use the core files to add Ajax-based
>   navigation with pushState and leverage some of the touch events and
>   other utilities with a very lightweight build (roughly 10k). Or, you
>   could add in specific UI widgets like form elements, listviews, etc.
>   to create an optimized build. We’re aiming to have a download builder
>   tool launch as part of 1.0 final in some form. We’re working on a
>   dependency map now for all the plugins to support this tool.

Until the Download Builder is released you can always head over to Github and download the decoupled widget: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/tree/master/js

Comment: FYI if using the decoupled widgets you will still need to minify them in order to reduce load times. Also performance is more of the JavaScript Engine the browser supports.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery Mobile is not a complete library, you will need jQuery 1.6.4.

jQuery Mobile is lightweight, and you can get a minified version which will be smaller in size. You should also look in to using a CDN for your library, like so:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
```

Instead of:

```
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
```

If you did't know, a CDN stands for Content Delivery Network, meaning the JQ library is hosted elsewhere, like on a Google or jQuery server, and delivered to your application. This way, if the user has already downloaded/used the library before, while browsing other websites, they won't have to download the library again. The benefits of this are better caching and decreased latency.

Answer (score 1):

I recently used jQuery mobile for a web app. If the application you are building is not extremely complex this library will work great for you. As a note read through their documentation as they recommend using slightly different events for the mobile/touch events(Example: vclick instead of click).

Answer (score 1):

- jQueryMobile 1.0.1 is dependent on jQuery 1.6.4
- jQM offers a minified version of the file for faster initial loading of the library
- 3G Connection loads fine with the CDN Hosted Minified files IMHO
- If your end use is on a Edge connection they should expect a slower load time IHMO
- [More information on jQM CDN, File sizes, etc...](http://jquerymobile.com/download/)

> Copy-and-Paste Snippet for CDN-hosted files (recommended):
>
> ```
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
> <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
> <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the low bandwidth version, use the "Minified and Gzipped: jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js", it's only 24kb.

Also, look into using the online versions:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
```

That way, if the user has already downloaded the scripts while browsing other sites, they won't have to download them again.

Also, you only need to include those 3 lines for moble.  The full jQuery isn't needed!

Good luck